# SQL Server : getting an error "Msg147, level15" Why do I get this error and how to fix it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following code

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT @FunderID
          FROM dbo.FunderCharityTbl
          WHERE @ContributionAmount > ( ( sum(TotalContributions) / 100 ) *10 )) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Sorry contribution is refused limit is breached', 16,1)
    RETRUN 99 
END
```

And I am getting the following error

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertContribution, Line 33
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

What I am trying to do is check if the `@contributionAmount` (entered amount) is greater than 10% of all the previous contributions made by the person with the entered `funderID` and if it is send an error message

I am relatively new to SQL and am wondering why you can't write the `If Exists` statement the way I did write it and what do I need to do to fix this error and have my procedure perform in the same manner as I wanted.

Comment: This is side issue, but why are you dividing by 100 and then multiplying by 10? Couldn't you just divide by 10?

Also, if you have a SQL statement that is not working it would be helpful for you to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did it like that because it is a percentage and if i change the percentage from 10% it will make more sense to me. I have clarified what I am trying to do (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Aggregate function in `WHERE` clause, but you can use it in `HAVING` clause

```
IF EXISTS(  SELECT  1 --@FunderID 
            FROM    dbo.FunderCharityTbl 
            HAVING  @ContributionAmount > ((sum(TotalContributions)/100)*10)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` something like:

```
IF EXISTS(  
    SELECT @FunderID 
    FROM dbo.FunderCharityTbl 
    GROUP BY @FunderID
    HAVING @ContributionAmount > ((sum(TotalContributions)/100)*10)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the message is pretty clear:  You cannot use an aggregation function in a `where` clause.  The appropriate clause is `having`.

The intent of your query is unclear.  Why are you returning a variable value?  In fact, with `EXISTS`, you can return anything.  I prefer `SELECT 1`.

I would guess that you are trying to determine if `@FunderID` has made more than a certain level of contributions.  You would do this as:

```
IF ( (SELECT (sum(TotalContributions)/100)*10
      FROM dbo.FunderCharityTbl
      WHERE FunderId = @FunderId
     ) > @ContributionAmount
   )
BEGIN
. . .
END;
```

Note:  I also encourage you to use `BEGIN`/`END` blocks whenever you use `IF`.

An alternative interpretation is that you want to determine if *any* funder has donated more than the specified amount:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT (sum(TotalContributions)/100)*10
            FROM dbo.FunderCharityTbl
            GROUP BY FunderId
            HAVING sum(TotalContributions)/100)*10 > @ContributionAmount
           ) 
    )
BEGIN
. . .
END;
```

Comment: When i try your second suggested method it says "Invalid Column name 'TotalContributions'" it also shows an error after the 'Having' Statement saying "epecting '(' or 'Select'"